# Is it possible to provision different instance types running in same ECS cluster?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

The cluster create wizard asks the EC2 instance type upfront. One can add or remove nodes using the autoscaling group. But how do I add a machine of different instance type?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  An ECS cluster is not strictly tied to an autoscaling group; see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35208003/112821).

You can launch additional EC2 instances separately from your autoscaling group or create an additional autoscaling group with a launch configuration that joins the instances to the same ECS cluster.  See the [ECS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html) for information on how to configure the ECS agent, including configuring which cluster the instance should join.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. If we can different types of instances on ECS, it is also possible to control the placement of containers on these nodes? What should I pass in the task/service definition so that they run only on d2.xl instances?

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal You can target individual instances during a task launch with the `StartTask` API. We're also enhancing the built-in schedulers with new placement strategies (including things like filters for instance types); you can learn more about that in this talk from re:Invent: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evYcLW3TLcQ.